# Problemas de compatibilidad con iPhone (HTML)

Tags: html, css, iphone

En la web que he hecho me han surgido problemas con los iPhones. Con todos los demás dispositivos funciona correctamente, tanto Android, Windows incluso con MacOS, con distintos navegadores. Pero si uso Safari en iOS me surgen varios problemas, como por ejemplo al visualizar un vídeo:

```
<video autoplay loop muted>
    <source src="../res/videos/video.mov">
</video>
```

Con ese código en todos los navegadores que abra la página web el video se autoreproduce, en cambio en ios sale el vídeo con el botón de play y si le das se abre el vídeo por así decirlo en una pestaña a parte.

Además tengo un botón para subir arriba que en todos los navegadores es tal que así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al abrirlo con un iPhone se ve mal, donde la flecha de dentro no está centrada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código del botón:

```
<button id="upbutton" class="hidden"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i></button>

#upbutton{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    position:fixed;
    border-width:3px;
    border-color:#FFFFFF;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:#337de6;
    opacity:0.6;
    bottom:90px;
    right:30px;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    font-size:30px;
    z-index:100;
}
```

Comment: El problema del video es algo conocido y que ya se ha comentado en otras preguntas (en resumen: en iOS, Safari no autoreproduce videos para ahorrar datos, y creo que lo mismo aplica para casi todos los navegadores móviles).

Comment: ¿Qué iOS tienes?

Answer (score 1):

El problema del video es algo conocido y que ya se ha comentado en otras preguntas. Resumiendo: generalmente en navegadores móviles no se autoreproducen videos para evitar que se haga un uso no deseado de datos.

Sobre cóme se ve la imagen mal en iPhone e iOS, he podido reproducir el problema. Me parece que se debe a cómo trata Safari la fuente y los *glyphicons*: como no le has puesto ningún estilo en particular, cada navegador lo interpretará como tenga definido por defecto.

Lo que podrías hacer es asegurarte que la flechita se colocará en el centro posicionándola de manera absoluta dentro del círculo azul. Algo como esto (que sí funciona en iOS):

```css
#upbutton{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    position:fixed;
    border-width:3px;
    border-color:#FFFFFF;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:#337de6;
    opacity:0.6;
    bottom:90px;
    right:30px;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    font-size:30px;
    z-index:100;
}

#upbutton i {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<button id="upbutton"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i></button>
```

Comment: En iOS10, ya permite la reproducción automática bajo ciertos puntos. He añadido una respuesta en la pregunta, quizás te interese leerla :)

Comment: Una vez cetrada la flecha en el circulo, tambien menhe dado cuenta que en vez de ser un círculo, es como una oval, esta achatado... como se puede solucionar esto?

Comment: @PavloB. ¿Seguro que no hay otro CSS que esté afectando al botón y que haga que se achate? Probando el código de la pregunta en iOS9 lo veo bien.

Comment: Si, seguro, solo hay un archivo css.

Comment: @PavloB. Ok, he podido ver el botón ovalado. Parece que es un problema por cómo iOS trata los bordes. Si le pones un ancho de borde de 0px, entonces parece que ya se ve el botón redondeado (como en este [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hjeadyve/2/)). Y si quieres que tenga ese borde blanco de 3 pixels (aunque sólido en lugar de outset), podrías ponerle una sombra interna (como en este otro [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hjeadyve/3/)).

Answer (score 1):

Si utilizan iOS 10, los vídeos ya pueden ser reproducidos automáticamente pero con algunas restricciones...

- El elemento `<video>` respetará el atributo `autoplay`, siempre y cuando se cumplan las siguientes condiciones:

  - Si no contienen pistas de audio.
  - `<video muted>` se reproducirá sin gesto de usuario también.
  - [Más información aquí](https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/)

Comment: Entonces, no hay manera de hacerlo funcionar sin tener ios 10? Siempre se quesará así?